# Find the Derivative $ 7^{\ln x} $ using first principle

Tags: calculus, limits

I still can't figure this out,

Question is Find the Derivative $ 7^{\ln(x)} $ using first principle

This is where I got

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{7^{\ln(x+h)} -  7^{\ln(x)}}{h}  $$

then What should I do?

Comment: Mind explaining the first principle?

Comment: @CuriousSciDude We will be better able to help you with the question if you explain what the first principle is.  Please update your question with this info ASAP so you have the best chance of being helped.

Comment: explain first principle???

Comment: @CuriousSciDude Yeah, I don't think the "first principle" is something that is common mathematical knowledge.  The question says to find the derivative *using the first principle*.  What is this first principle we are supposed to use?

Comment: $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{{f(x+h)}}-f(x)}{h}$$

Comment: @CuriousSciDude So you mean you want to find the derivative using the limit definition of derivative.

Comment: yeah, like f(x+h) - f(x) /h as h -> 0

Comment: I believe first principle refers to using what wikipedia has under the "[Rigorous Definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Rigorous_definition)" section.  I feel like I've heard this terminology as well, but not sure where (I see a lot of the related posts have it as well).

Answer (score 3):

Note that calculating derivative of $f(x)$ *via first principles* means that we need to calculate the limit $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$$ without using any rules of differentiation.

Here $f(x) = 7^{\log x}$ and we can proceed as follows
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}\notag\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{7^{\log(x + h)} - 7^{\log x}}{h}\notag\\
&= 7^{\log x}\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{7^{\log(x + h) - \log x} - 1}{h}\notag\\
&= 7^{\log x}\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{7^{\log(x + h) - \log x} - 1}{\log(x + h) - \log x}\cdot\frac{\log(x + h) - \log x}{h}\notag\\
&= 7^{\log x}\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{7^{\log(x + h) - \log x} - 1}{\log(x + h) - \log x}\cdot\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\log(x + h) - \log x}{h}\notag\\
&= 7^{\log x}\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{7^{t} - 1}{t}\cdot\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\log((x + h)/x)}{h}\text{ (by putting }t = \log(x + h) - \log x)\notag\\
&= 7^{\log x}\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{e^{t\log 7} - 1}{t}\cdot\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + (h/x))}{h}\notag\\
&= 7^{\log x}\lim_{t \to 0}\log 7 \cdot\frac{e^{t\log 7} - 1}{t\log 7}\cdot\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + (h/x))}{h/x}\cdot\frac{1}{x}\notag\\
&= \frac{7^{\log x}\log 7}{x}\lim_{y \to 0}\cdot\frac{e^{y} - 1}{y}\cdot\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + z)}{z}\text{ (putting }y = t\log 7, z = h/x)\notag\\
&= \frac{7^{\log x}\log 7}{x}\cdot 1\cdot 1\notag\\
&= \frac{7^{\log x}\log 7}{x}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Note that $7^{\ln(x)} = \left(e^{\ln(7)} \right)^{\ln(x)} = \left(e^{\ln(x)} \right)^{\ln(7)} = x^{\ln(7)}$.

From the generalized binomial theorem, we have
$$(x+h)^{\alpha} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dbinom{\alpha}k x^{\alpha-k}h^k = x^{\alpha} + \alpha x^{\alpha-1}h + h^2 f(x,h;\alpha)$$
where $f(x,0;\alpha)$ is continuous in $h$ with $f(x,0;\alpha) = 0$. Hence,
$$\dfrac{(x+h)^{\alpha}-x^{\alpha}}h = \alpha x^{\alpha-1} + hf(x,h;\alpha)$$
Hence, we have
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{(x+h)^{\alpha}-x^{\alpha}}h = \alpha x^{\alpha-1} + \lim_{h \to 0}hf(x,h;\alpha) = \alpha x^{\alpha-1}$$

Hence, we have
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{7^{\ln(x+h)}-7^{\ln(x)}}h = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{(x+h)^{\ln(7)}-x^{\ln(7)}}h = \ln(7)x^{\left(\ln(7)-1\right)}$$

Comment: But the answer is ${7^{ln(x)}*lnx}/x$

Comment: @CuriousSciDude: Answer given here is correct and if you like it your way it should be visible as $7^{\log x}\log 7/x$ and not $7^{\log x}\log x/x$.

Comment: I like your use of $a^{\log b} = b^{\log a}$ equality, but since my daily voting limit is reached I can't upvote your answer. will do that tomorrow.

Comment: I doubt that generalized binomial series counts as "first principles".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is "first principle" or not, but since $7^a = e^{(\ln x)(\ln 7)}$ for any real $a$ you have $$7^{\ln x} = e^{(\ln x)(\ln 7)}.$$ Thus $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{7^{\ln(x+h)} - 7^{\ln x}}{h} = \frac d{dx} e^{(\ln x)(\ln 7)}$$ which you can compute using the usual rules of differentiation.

Comment: I might try this one lol,

Comment: I think using "first principle" would mean taking the limit and show that it matches the "usual rules of differentiation".

Comment: Yeah, 
Well I want the steps to solve that limit I gave basicallY

Comment: I don't think this is quite right: $7^{\ln(x)}=e^{\ln(7) \ln(x)}$.

Comment: Yeah, a silly mistake on my part. I corrected it.

Comment: @user46944 thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

This is the derivative of $(7)^{\ln x}$ or the derivative of $e^{\ln x\cdot  \ln 7}$ or the derivative of $x^{\ln 7}$ which is $\ln 7 \cdot x^{(\ln 7) -1}=(1/x)\ln7\cdot x^{\ln7}$.

Comment: I wanna solve that limit dude,

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{7^{\ln(x+h)}-7^{\ln(x)}}{h}=$$
$$7^{\ln(x)}\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{7^{\ln(x+h)-\ln(x)}-7^{\ln(x)-\ln(x)}}{h}$$
$$7^{\ln(x)}\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{7^{\ln(1+h/x)}-1}{h}$$
I use the Maclaurin series expansion of $\ln(1+x)=x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4+\,\dots$: 
$$7^{\ln(x)}\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{7^{h/x}-1}{h}$$
$$7^{\ln(x)}\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(7^{1/x})^h-1}{h}$$
Now I use the well-known limit $\displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}=\ln(a)$:

$$7^{\ln(x)}\ln(7^{1/x})=\frac{7^{\ln(x)}\ln(7)}{x}$$

Comment: you have a curious fallacy where you replace $\log(1 + (h/x))$ with $h/x$. There is no general rule which allows such replacements.

Comment: @Paramanand: This is indeed true. It had to use the Maclaurin series approximation, otherwise I was stuck. Fortunately, I could get the correct derivative. I admit your reasoning is far better.